# While loop stops at if statement - pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Whenever I run this code, it stops right before the `screen.blit` while still looping, printing the `'debug3'` over and over.

It doesn't even recognize that the screen is not defined, and my intention is for it to run the `screen.blit`.

```
...
playermove = 5
walkL=pygame.image.load("files/sprites/walkL.png")
walkR=pygame.image.load("files/sprites/walkR.png")
currentSprite = walkL

#single sprite size (width, height)
h=128
w=57   
numImages = 4
    #counter
cImage=0


class Player:

    def animation(self):    
        global cImage,numImages,currentSprite,playerRect,w,h        
        if (cImage>=numImages-1):
            cImage=0
        else:
            cImage+=1
        print('debug3')

        screen.blit(currentSprite,playerRect, (cImage*w,0,w,h))

while True:
    player.animation()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your else statement, you need to indent the 'print' call to line up with 'cImage += 1'.

----snippet from code example----

```
    if (cImage>=numImages-1):
        cImage=0
    else:
        cImage+=1
    print('debug3')
```

------- end code snippet---------------